# Linq TO SQL Query Pending Inserted Records

Tags: lambda, linq-to-sql

I need to query the DataContext for data and have it return what is on the back end and also any pending updates and inserts.  Getting the pending updates is easy, L2S does that already without much issue. But pending inserts, are a different beast and behave differently in different situations.

```
Data before any Update/Insert:
PersonKey  FirstName      LastName      DateOfBirth
1          RICHARD        JONES         NULL
2          PAUL           ROGERS        01/21/1945

    int key = 1;
    NtsSuiteDataContext DbContext = new NtsSuiteDataContext();
    Person newPerson = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "DAVID",
        LastName = "SMITH"
    };
    DbContext.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(newPerson);

    Person updatePerson = DbContext.Persons.First(p => p.PersonKey == key);
    updatePerson.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1970, 1, 2);

    var personList = DbContext.Persons.ToList();

Data after any Update/Insert:
PersonKey  FirstName      LastName      DateOfBirth
1          RICHARD        JONES         01/02/1970
2          PAUL           ROGERS        01/21/1945
```

Now, I know I can query the DbContext.GetChangeSet().Inserts for those types of inserts, but to do this for every query gets a bit dirty when writing code.

Here I have another example, with link table, two different queries one returns the inserted record one doesn't. I kind of understand, but still, why would L2S be able to get the record that I created here in one query but not in the other.

```
Data before any update/inserts
PersonContactKey    PersonKey     ContactKey  ContactTypeKey
1                   1             1           1

    Person person = DbContext.Persons.First(p => p.PersonKey == key);
    PersonContact newPersonContact = new PersonContact
    {
        ContactTypeKey = 1,
            Description = "(555) 111-2222
    };
    DbContext.PersonContacts.InsertOnSubmit(newPersonContact);
    person.PersonContacts.Add(newPersonContact);
    newContact.PersonContacts.Add(newPersonContact);

    var list1 = DbContext.PersonContacts.Where(pc => pc.Person.PersonKey == key).ToList();
    var list2 = DbContext.Persons.First(p => p.PersonKey == key).PersonContacts.ToList();


list1 only has only the one personcontact record that already exists.
list2 has both the existing personcontact record and the new record  created above. 

Data after any update/inserts (list1)
PersonContactKey    PersonKey     ContactTypeKey  Description
1                   1             1               (123) 456-7890

Data after any update/inserts (list2)
PersonContactKey    PersonKey     ContactTypeKey  Description
1                   1             1               (123) 456-7890
0                   1             1               (555) 111-2222
```

TIA for any comments and help.  I understand this is how it is, just thought maybe someone had a better way to getting INSERTED records, if I re-queried those entities before I issued a SubmitChanges() to the DataContext.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24310347/2557128) seems relevant.

Comment: Yes, I was doing that, but in order to make sure a UNION doesn't bring in duplicate records, I will need to create an IEqualityComparer class.  This will just add extra work for each table I query from the data context.

Comment: I don't see how a `Union` with pending inserts could duplicate with existing database records? Unless you have the potential to insert already existing records that will reject?